# What path should I use for Meteor's Webapp API?

Tags: http, meteor

I'm using Meteor v1.9 Webapp API to have my app listen to HTTP requests, specifically from a link to the app itself from a website, let's say example.org.

The documentation says to use

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use([path], handler)
```

Where the [path] is defined as such:

> path - an optional path field. This handler will only be called on
> paths that match this string. The match has to border on a / or a ..
> For example, /hello will match /hello/world and /hello.world, but not
> /hello_world.

**My question:**
Let's say my meteor application is hosted on **abc.com** and the POST data being sent over to it is from **example.org** (where the link to abc.com is as well).
For the [path] argument mentioned above, in this case, should I have it as **"/example"** since example.org is where my app is listening to requests from (getting the POST data)? Or does it have to be a different format? I tried the former, but it doesn't seem to be working for it, so I'm trying to find the root of the issue.

Additional information that might be useful: I know it says 'optional' so I tried omitting it, but  when I tested it out via 'meteor run' where it runs off of localhost:3000, it just yielded a blank page, with no errors and a success sent back, probably because it uses a GET request instead of POST.
My code for the webapp in my meteor application is as follows:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/[example]", async (req, res, next) => {
        userName = req.body;
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
});
```

Also technically my meteor application is built/bundled and deployed as a Node.js application on the website, but that shouldn't affect anything regarding this as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That path is the path (part of the URL) on your meteor server. So in your example, for instance,

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/example", async (req, res, next) => {
        userName = req.body;
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
});
```

means that you will need to send your POST requests to `abc.com/example`.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense. Sounds like I should omit it then. Is it possible to the program 'ignore' a request if it's running on my localhost:3000 so that it doesn't show a blank page when I'm testing?